# Custom Segue Portrait Mode

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to create a custom segue to change and lock my next view into portrait mode, no matter how the device is rotated. I was able to create my UIStoryBoardSegue files, but now I am stuck with the code to switch from landscape to portrait... this is what I did so far:

```
-(void) perform

{
        self.appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        UIViewController *source = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
        UIViewController *destination = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;



    }
```

And now I am stuck... help!

Comment: Are you pushing from the first to the second controller or presenting modally? Overriding supportedInterfaceOrientations works fine for modal presentations. I don't know if what you're trying to do is possible for a push, since it's the navigation controller itself that's rotated. Trying to do it using a custom segue won't work any better than your other attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are writting for iOS 6 or per iOS 6, but if it is iOS 6, try placing the following code in the view controller that you are trying to set its orientation.

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft   | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}
```

Now the method above has all the masks and you can remove the masks you don't need. There is really no need to access the app delegate for rotation setting any more. Hope this helps you achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to overload the `supportedDeviceOrientations` method of a view controller subclass like this

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIDeviceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Comment: Your code works for per iOS 6. Since then orientations are defined by masks.